# Where to find Terminal in Raspbmc

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbmc

I installed Raspbmc on my Raspberry Pi. It's working fine but I'm not able to find the terminal.

How can I go about finding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exit `xbmc` from the menu (not shutdown).  At the white screen, press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.  You should now have a login prompt.  Username: `pi` Password: `raspberry`.

To start `xbmc` again:

```
sudo initctl start xbmc
```

or reboot the Pi.

Note that there is a site specifically for [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) questions (that aren't generic Unix/Linux ones).

Comment: thanks gareth, it works, but now I am stuck with terminal, please tell me how to exit from it

Answer (score 0):

dose <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> work?, and maybe other F keys. This works on many Gnu+Linux operating systems. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> is usual for X11 (to get you back), though it is not universal, so experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Is your raspbmc set up on the network?  If so, I'd recommend just connecting in via ssh from another machine rather than via the local console.  That is normally dedicated to the XBMC interface.